# orbeon forms - date validation

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I have got input with date binding

```
<xf:bind nodeset="ns:date_1" relevant="true()" type="xs:date"   />
```

and Orbeon creates inptut with datepicker, but it also requires me to fill it with date, otherwise it adds `xforms-invalid` css class.
How can I make it optional not required?

I've already tried adding attribute `required="true()"`, but nothing happens.

Comment: Have you tried `required="False"`?

Answer (score 1):

I found it:

instead of

```
type="xs:date"
```

declare

```
type="xf:date"
```